# Isn't window.location.replace() supposed to disable the back button?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a site where people need to be able to click a button to "escape" the page without logging the page in history.

According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace, window.location.replace() is supposed to disable the back button of the browser as well as not save the previous url in the history.

This does not seem to be the case in Chrome or Edge. Is there any way to do this with Javascript?

Comment: You've misunderstood the documentation. The "back" button is not disabled.

Comment: _“the current page will not be saved in session History, meaning the user won't be able **to use** the back button to navigate **to it**.”_

Comment: What exact behaviour *are* you seeing then?

Comment: if you navigate to page1, then page2 and you do a replace('page3'), then if you click back button on page3 you will go back to page1 (and not page2)